# How enable filter input in the CGridView + yii2

Tags: yii2

I want to show filter input at table below, can you help me for this?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Add validation rules for these fields in your search model.

Comment: Hope it helps http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/